# Detecting if a user switches tabs inside a UITabBar on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, viewwillappear

Good day,

I am having a little bit of a problem.  I want to track user behavior for an app.  The app has a tab bar with 5 tabs.  Every time a user switches tabs, I'd like to know about it.  That's all I want to do.

Which method should I use here?

viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear are not getting called.

A UINavigationController actually puts this UITabBar as the UINavigationController's root view (did I describe that right?).  To be very clear, the user launches the app.  There are several buttons.  If you press one of them, you are taken to that UITabBar with its 5 associated tabs.  (In the UITabBar there is a UINavigationBar that will take you to back to the home screen.).  How do I get notified when the user presses tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5--no matter which order or how many times these tabs are pressed?

Do I need a UINavigationController delegate to be implemented?  If so, I'm not sure where to put that code.  Or is there something simpler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol. Set your tabBarController's delegate to `self` (most likely) and implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I think that I need to use UITabBar, not the full controller because I have a custom UITabBar (it has 10 tabs, and the tabbar slides horizontally. This is in contrast to the standard TabBar, which makes you click on a "more" tab if you want to have more than 5 tabs. Knowing this constraint, is there another way? I see a UITabBar protocol which has a didselectItem method, which I am already using but do you think that is likely to work?  I'll give it a shot.  I think that it just might do the trick.  I posted by thinking for others who are in the same boat.

Comment: Oh, I see... So yes, the UITabBar delegate method will likely allow you to achieve the same thing, since it tells you when each tab is selected, and from that you can likely do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use UITabbarControllerDelegate and provide UITabarController with delegate, which will adopt this protocol.